# Non recursive makefile example

Tags: makefile

I've visited many links including Peter Miller's PDF about non recursive make but I still can't find a simple example on how to implement it.

I've googled for hours but many of them seem to be over-complicated and hard to tell the flow of things.

Can somebody show an example of a couple of directories? I'd like to see how the makefile scales as more directories are added.

Maybe for something like:

```
/src/
|->main.cc

|->dirA/a.cc
|->dirA/module.mk

|->dirB/b.cc
|->dirB/module.mk

/include/
|->main.h
|->a.h
|->b.h
```

Then have `main.o` require `a.o` and `b.o` to be compiled into one executable.

Thanks for any tips and guidance in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said much about what you want this system to do. Here's a crude but effective solution:

**/src/Makefile:**

```
vpath %.h include

main: main.o
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.cc
    $(CXX) -c -Iinclude $< -o $@     # not the best way, but maybe the clearest

include dirA/module.mk
include dirB/module.mk
```

**/src/dirA/module.mk:**

```
main: dirA/a.o

dirA/a.o: a.h
```

**/src/dirB/module.mk:**

```
main: dirB/b.o

dirB/b.o: b.h
```

There is more you can do, once you have this much working.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my answer. But basically have `main.o` require both `a.o` and `b.o` to be compiled into one executable. But this looks pretty awesome as far as I can tell :)

Comment: @Tek: You mean "linked", not "compiled". I inferred that you wanted an executable, and called it `main` (because you hadn't specified). The `main` rule does this.

Comment: Er, yes. Sorry I've been researching this all night and it's midnight. I'm a little absent-minded at the moment. But anyways, would you mind describing the "clearest" versus the "best" way on the commented line? It would help what you mean to me and many others that read this. Thanks for the great example so far!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example:
https://github.com/cppfw/prorab/tree/master/tests

There is a main makefile which includes all makefiles from subdirectories.